# Pagination angularjs

Tags: angularjs, pagination

i have an input text, so when the user enter a name and click at a buttom, a list of clients having this name appear.

```
<body ng-app="myClientApp">
<div ng-controller="consulterctr">
<div>
<input type="text" ng-model="name"/>
<button ng-click="research()"></button>
</div>

<table class="table table-hover table-bordered" id="tab1">

     <thead>
        <tr class="row-name" >
           <th >Nom</th>
           <th>Prenom</th>
           <th>Code</th>
         </tr>
     </thead>
 <tbody>

    <tr class="row-content"  ng-repeat="cl in clientPD| startFrom:currentPage*pageSize | limitTo:pageSize">

           <td>{{cl.nomClient}}</td>
                <td>{{cl.prenomClient}}</td>
                <td>{{cl.codeClient}}</td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
</table>

<div class="container spacer" style="margin-left: 0px; margin-bottom: 30px;">


    <button ng-disabled="currentPage == 0" ng-click="currentPage=currentPage-1">
        Précédent
    </button>
    {{currentPage+1}}/{{numberOfPages()}}
    <button ng-disabled="currentPage >= clientPD.length/pageSize - 1" ng-click="currentPage=currentPage+1">
        Next
    </button>
    </div>

</div>
</body>
```

This is angularsjs code:

```
   app.controller("consulterctr", function ($scope,$http,$window,$route) {
        $scope.pageSize=4;
        $scope.currentPage=0;

    $scope.numberOfPages=function(){
            return Math.ceil($scope.clientPD.length/$scope.pageSize);                
        };

    $scope.research=function(){

            $http.get("/client/"+$scope.name)
            .then(function (response) {         
                $scope.clientPD=response.data;

            },function (error){
                console.log(error, 'can not get data.');
            }); 
        };
});
    app.filter('startFrom', function() {
        return function(input, start) {
            start = +start; //parse to int
            return input.slice(start);
        }
    });
```

The pagination works perfectly, i can navigate throught pages, but i found just one problem. For example, if i search for Harry, this name have 2 pages. if i'm now in the second page, and i decided to serach for David and David have just one page, when i click serach, i will get an empty page and the currentPage still 2 and not return to the first page, so i have to return to the page one to find david informations. Thanks.

Comment: can you post your working fiddle?

Comment: Can you provide me $scope.clientPD data format with dummy content.

Answer (score 0):

You should reset currentPage every time you call your search function in order to start from first page otherwise because of

`startFrom:currentPage*pageSize`

Your ng-repeat will not start from first item if current page is different than 0.

```
$scope.research=function(){  
    $http.get("/client/"+$scope.name).then(function (response) { 
        $scope.currentPage = 0;        
        $scope.clientPD=response.data;
    },function (error){
        console.log(error, 'can not get data.');
      }); 
    };
});
```

[Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/8Cz6P2TecZoKDU096A2J?p=preview)

Comment: I tried this solution before, the same problem again !! this not solve it

Comment: Added plunker for you